# Extracting the right data?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a `data.frame` = x which contains the data and the label extracted from one person, these are extractable as `x$data` and `x$labels`.

The data is stored as `matrix` where each row is an observation, and each column is the feature extracted from that observation.

The labels is an list which describes the class of that observation,

So if `Label[1] = "banana"`

Will the observation in the first row reside within the class "banana", and thus also the features extracted.

I am at at moment trying extract a data matrix only containing the label  = "banana"..

```
x$data[x$labels=="banana"]
```

Problem is though that i am missing the matrix structure, which i had in the data.

Is it possible extract it with in a matrix structure?

Simple example:

```
data = matrix(data = c(rbind(sample(1:10, 5)),rbind(sample(1:10, 5)),rbind(sample(1:10, 5)),rbind(sample(1:10, 5)),rbind(sample(1:10, 5))), ncol = 5, nrow = 5)

data 

>         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    8    5   10    4    4
[2,]    5   10    3    9    3
[3,]    7    1    9    8    8
[4,]    6    2    8    6    9
[5,]   10    4    2    1    5


label = matrix(data = c(rbind("banana","banana","juice", "poop", "air")) ,nrow = 5)
>         [,1]    
[1,] "banana"
[2,] "banana"
[3,] "juice" 
[4,] "poop"  
[5,] "air"

data[label == "banana"]

>[1]  8  5  5 10 10  3  4  9  4  3
```

Here it would be nice to extract as a matrix.

Comment: Can you please share an example dataset that illustrates your problem and expected output?

Comment: I think you are looking for `data.frame(x$data[x$labels=="banana"])`

Comment: The data has to be extracted as a matrix..

Comment: You could try `x <- as.matrix(x)` before attempting `x$data[x$labels=="banana"]`

Comment: the data.frame does contain other stuff than that.. So it would be appreciated if i didn't change the data.frame itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. That was easier than I thought...

```
matrix(x$data[x$labels=="banana"],ncol = ncol(x$data)
```

Comment: might as well accept your own answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
data[label == "banana",]
```